# What is the name of this chord

Tags: chord-progressions

I'm sure this has been asked before but I cannot find in anywhere. Say you are in the key of C major. What is the name of a dominant chord on the 6th scale degree, i.e. A C# E G. This device is ubiquitous in pop music, and off the top of my head 'Fallen Down' from the Undertale soundtrack is the first simple tune that comes to mind which features it. I have been mentally referring to this as a Neapolitan chord but this  is a different harmonic device.

Comment: Unclear: the name of the chord is of course **A7**, or **VI7**. What more are you looking for? Some clarification in the question title and in the body of the question might be helpful, but any more detailed explanations would require more information about the context in which the chord is found.

Comment: @DavidBowling I was just wondering if this chord had a name, really. A name might mean I could find pointed information on its history and usage. I hit a break in my search with the term 'VI7' and It seems as though it's so elementary and ubiquitous that it doesn't have one

Comment: Again, context matters. It is likely a _secondary dominant_, e.g. in the common **I - VI - ii - V** "Rhythm changes" variation.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes that sounds about right, or rather, consistent with how I hear it. The example I mentioned in the OP goes I - IV - IV - iv. Another example is the progression I - VI7 - ii - IV. The contexts that I am thinking of are essentially when it is juxtaposed with the root chord so you get the really nice voice leading of the one to the flat two or vice versa.

Comment: The "name" of the chord is independent of the context within the progression.  As has been stated it is A7 (regardless of the key).  Being in C identifies the root as being on the 6th degree of the key and Tim's answer describes that dynamic.  But the chord is identified by its formula (1, 3, 5) = Maj, (1, b3, 5) = min, (1, 3, 5, b7) = dom 7, etc, etc.

Comment: @ggcg -- a quibble: sometimes a context is required to even name a chord. Symmetric chords (i.e. dim7 and aug) need context to identify the root, and other chords are ambiguous in isolation (e.g. m6  and m7b5).

Answer (score 3):

Often it'll be a *secondary dominant* or V/V, V/ii, V/iii, V/vi. In other words, it's non-diatonic (containing C#), and often leads, in this case, to Dm. It's the V of Dm, - A7. It *can* be named VI7, but that doesn't give much of a clue as to what it's actually doing in relation to other chords around it. But if it doesn't lead to Dm (ii), then it's more of a standalone, and can be labelled VI7.

So to sum up, in key C major, it's called, in RN, V7/ii. Or simply, A dominant 7.